# Pytesseract can not recognize even very simple textline

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

[Binary image B2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7iWh.jpg)
[Binary image Y2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjude.jpg)

I think these images are quite simple and clear. Still pytesseract does not work. I really wonder why.

Here is my code

```
from pytesseract import pytesseract as tesseract
import cv2 as cv

binary = cv.imread(filepath)

lang = 'eng'
config = 'tessedit_char_whitelist=RGB123'
print(tesseract.image_to_string(binary, lang=lang, config=config))
```

The output is just blank string.

Comment: Does the issue persist if you rotate the image and then try to run tesseract on the rotated image?

Answer (score 0):

To Dennlinger's point, I would definitely rotate it before sending it through PyTess. PyTess *should* rotate it automatically though. Should.

Alternatively, I see in your configuration that you have white listed "RGB123" which, correct me if I'm wrong, may mean that PyTess is mainly looking for those specific numbers and characters.

I'd try changing your configuration by omiting that configuration so that it can pick up the "Y" in there.

Comment: Uh it should be "RYB123"  and it was a stupid mistake
and "RYB123" does not work either

Comment: also rotating it with "np.rot90" does not work